# Keycloak integration with Github Identity Provider

Tags: keycloak, token-exchange

I am using Postman with the Authorization code type OAuth 2.0 to generate an access token for my APIs. This setup is configured to use Keycloak as the authentication provider. **Everything works as expected when i log in using Keycloak user credentials**. However, when i attempt to log in using Github as identity provider, I encounter an error at the final stage. The error message is as follows:

```
POST https://{host:port}/realms/{myrealm}/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Response Body: `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Code not valid"}`

Steps to reproduce:

Keycloak version: 21.1.1

1. In Keycloak, I create a GitHub Identity Provider within my realm and
   provide the ClientId and ClientSecret of my GitHub OAuth
   application. I also enable token storage. Note: The "First Login
   flow" is set to "first broker login," and the "Post login flow" is
   set to "None."
2. On GitHub, I set the homepage URL and the authorization callback URL
   as the Redirect URI for the Keycloak Identity Provider for GitHub.
3. In Postman, under the Authorization tab, I configure OAuth 2.0 as
   follows:

> Token name: testing
>
> Grant type: Authorization Code
>
> Auth URL:
> https://{host:port}/realms/{myrealm}/protocol/openid-connect/auth
>
> Access Token URL:
> https://{host:port}/realms/{myrealm}/protocol/openid-connect/token
>
> ClientId: The ClientId of my client application in Keycloak
>
> ClientSecret: The ClientSecret of my client application in Keycloak
>
> Client Authentication: Send as Basic Auth header

Note: I made sure that it is not using the same authorization code by regenerating the client secret for my client application and it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by enabling key features during the Keycloak installation, including preview, token_exchange, and admin_fine_grained_authz.